# How to store more values in Google Pie Chart

Tags: javascript

I want to show 3 values in

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Your Current Work Effort (hours/week)', <?php echo $_SESSION['timeDayFeild'];?>],
    ['Can Be Utilized By Us (hours/week)', <?php echo $_SESSION['remainingFeild'];?>]
]);
```

i want to show

1. Your Current work effort
2. Session values
3. hours/week